# .htaccess Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess

Im using this .htaccess to add "?timestamp" at end of my url 
example:

```
example.com/pagename?201502201855
```

all is ok but if i navigat to page and page is

```
example.com/page/2/?201502211929
```

then i get error This webpage has a redirect loop Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}##%{QUERY_STRING} ^([^#]+)##\1
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}##%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^#]+)##\1
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you are causing a redirect loop, and this means you need a RewriteCond to prevent the redirect happening a second time.

Here's a simple which adds a timestamp to your URL anytime you add "showtime" to the query string. This is also a bit cleaner than your current code as the timestamp is assigned to a variable in the RewriteCond then reused in the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} showtime [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?time=%1 [R,L]
```

In the above example, the redirect is only occuring if 'showtime' is present in the querystring, so the redirect won't be repeated.  Perhaps a similar method could be used in your script to ensure the redirect doesn't keep happening?

For example, this code will always add a timestamp, but prevent the redirect loop by checking for "timestamp" in the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !timestamp [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?timestamp=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: this is ok but there is a problem.
if i link is example.com/page/20150228124046

after user visit that link an time changed.(the link still will have old timestamp)